# Contrast and readability

Tags: discussion, design

It seems that with the new design of SO, the designers have forsaken readability for a lower contrast design. I have good vision, but I found myself leaning in to see some of the design features/new font colors. I despair for users with impaired vision.

If this trend is to continue, can we expect a completely white page with slightly off-white fonts in 5 years time?

Contrast. Needs more. Desperately.

Comment: Agreed.  My tired old eyes are having a bit of trouble with the "Microsofting" of the design.

Comment: While I like the new font, I agree that the contrast makes it hard on my eyes. Especially the difference between questions that are highlighted as interesting and not.

Comment: Absolutely +1! Now it is quite hard to distinguish the highlighted questions (those matching your favorite tags).

Comment: @HotLicks, agreed!  Not *everyone* has the vision acuity or a 20 or 30 yr old.

Comment: Agreed. I especially dont like the low contrast on highlighted questions because of favorite tags.

Comment: I loaded Stylebot on Chrome a few hours ago just so I could correct all the CSS changes that make things hard to read. And why are HTML tags in code examples now bold, while the rest of the code is normal?

Comment: I'm not quite colour-blind, but I do not have _full_ colour vision. I'm struggling to differentiate between posts I have upvoted on the main SO site.

Comment: also consider laptop monitors, when slightly bended it results in low contrast items being not really visible.

Comment: Already raised and ignored for Meta Stack Overflow http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229862/could-we-mute-the-theme-a-little#comment761072_229862 - obviously SO want the 20 year old newbies rather than experienced people with failing eyes

Comment: After zooming in for two times I asked myself whether I'm already that old that I need so large text...

Comment: In my mid-twenties and I still can't read it either.

Comment: Who thought this new design was a good idea? It's horrible. If you're trying to scroll quickly and identify which questions you've looked at, it's impossible to see. @HotLicks, called it "Microsofting", but I think it could equally be called "Appleing" since they seem to be in to making everything white with no contrast also (zoom out on an Xcode storyboard and try to see where the controllers are).

Comment: Hah! I was going to agree with you @FunctionR, then I remembered that I'm 41...

Comment: I want to have a word with the guy who [looked at this](http://i.imgur.com/rZzJTBe.png) and said "yea, that looks *good*".  Then, his boss who approved.

Comment: For the record, I'm young with great vision (no color blindness, 20/20) and the first thing I noticed was the awful lack of contrast. This new design doesn't seem to work for *anybody*.

Comment: I blame the mobile-trend for this... just for the sake to blame something.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau - Like I said, I blame "Microsofting".  It's trying to be consistent with the ugly Windows 8/9 scheme.

Comment: I've been curious if there a no more questions in my favorite tags or someone has adjusted my display when I couldn't find any favorite tag questions anymore. Glad that I found this post, my display wasn't manipulated and questions are still asked...

Comment: @HotLicks IMO there are definite elements of Windows XP in the new design, like the orange highlight on the "interesting/featured/hot/..." tabs. Nothing says "we're with it" like rolling out visual elements of an OS from 2001 in 2015.

Comment: I dont know about others, but I use FF on Ubuntu and there is a lot of white, and the brightness is just too much for my eyes. It is hard to focus and read something. A grayish color would be more soothing I think.

Comment: @rdelmar it's also "Googling;" remember when the totally washed out Gmail rolled out? (They also did the same to Reader, right before they axed it, RIP)

Comment: I'm visually-impaired, and I could not agree more.  I like some of the subtle changes that have been made, such as the blue links on the user profile page, and I can definitely see what the designers were trying to do, but this is almost unusable for me.  Subtle shades are very trendy right now, but they are also highly lacking in terms of function (i.e. readability).

Comment: Yes, please increase the weight of the fonts - I had to go up a zoom level to regain (some) readability. I'm 46, with perfectly-prescribed lenses for short-sightedness, and a monitor calibrated for working in VS with a mostly-white background colour, and SO is *still* too low-contrast.

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru StackExchane does not support text zooming see last comment to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219799/adding-a-comment-hides-parts-of-earlier-comments

Comment: @Mark I'm not talking about text zooming - I meant that in order to glean enough information about the shape of the (now too low-contrast) text to be able to read it, I had to tell Chrome to crank up the page zoom level and make *everything* bigger. Which also means, of course, that less fits on the screen, and you get less attention because I have to scroll much more...

Comment: Which is why text zooming is better as the parts of the screen don't enlarge - you still have tom scroll more but for readable text that would be better - However I suspect it is the font that matter here not its size

Comment: It's especially hard to read on my laptop, which has lower resolution.

Comment: Is it my imagination, or did the yellow background in SO questions is "yellower"? (or did I just adjusted the contrast of my eyes to this new background?) If the answer to the first is "yes", then Great! If not... well, one get's used to (almost) everything (that sounds so "Microsoftish")

Comment: It would be great if we could have some feedback on this question (and possibly any design changes that are incoming) as I'm really struggling to look at the new design for any period of time. I like how it looks but the contrast is horrible for me and so washed out I feel like I'm getting snow blindness!

Answer (score 71):

I propose that either of these options should be considered:

1. A roll back to what we had before. It was not perfect, but it got the job done.

`OR`

2. Add more contrast as suggested by OP above.

Answer (score 35):

The new font/color/spacing whatever on the main question listing page is terrible.  The sanserif font, in that pale (blue?) color, with the letter spacing used, causes the letters to run together WORSE THAN IF IT WAS TYPED IN ALL CAPS.

Comment: I don't think I've found a single style change in this new design that I've liked yet.

Comment: @j08691 I mostly agree with your comment, sadly.

Comment: I like the light yellow for block quotes, and larger font when typing comments and....well not much else.

Comment: Is this regarding SO, meta-SO, or _meta-SE_? The design is terrible across the board, but the specific issues seem to be conflated throughout the comments here.

Comment: @Mathletics - Mainly I'm complaining about SO, as that is where I spend most of my time.

Comment: In that case I agree 100%; I'm not the type generally opposed to change, but the new typefaces and contrast are severely hindering readability. FWIW I am 29 with great eyes.

Answer (score 24):

Personally, my eyes are really sensitive plus I'm color blind. I'm barely reading. These white pages are too much shiny for people like me. SO really should put a switch-design thing for switch to ex-new. You can't imagine how hard it is if you're color blind.

Answer (score -54):

Design is hard. Too much contrast is bad for your eyes, too little is hard to read. Getting that nice middle is tough to do across the board. Not to be seen as an excuse, but poor monitor calibration may make things harder to read than intended. Apple does a great job calibrating the monitors for their computers, but PC users often see a wide variance in colors and white/dark levels on their monitors. Calibrating your monitor may help your computer experience for all applications:

http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-calibrate-your-monitor/

Edit: Talk about too much contrast, some example how too much can be hard to read: http://writer2001.com/colwebcontrast.htm

TL;DR - Since many can't read all the way through a paragraph, this is a work around you can try. Not a guarantee. Obviously.

Comment: "Not to be seen as an excuse" or did you not read that far?

Comment: I am on  an Apple computer and have difficulty reading - and please quote a study showing "Too much contrast is bad for your eyes" I get eyestrain when there is too little

Comment: "poor monitor calibration may make things harder to read than intended"... I think that's the part that seems like a "blame it on the user" comment (or worse: "blame it on your hardware manufacturer"). Anyway, with the previous color scheme I had not a single problem, but with this one I simply can't tell wether a question background is yellow or white! (and I use both PC and Mac) The text font also makes it somewhat harder to read the posts... I think this new layout is simply a poor choice, and should be reversed (the previous one worked quite well)

Comment: First Google result, many others: http://www.writer2001.com/colwebcontrast.htm

Comment: Most of the time these types of design changes don't get reversed. SO may be different and listen to a minor group of people complain, but calibrating your monitor is a quick fix you can do now instead of waiting for SO's design team to tweak things. That's all I was saying. Lets all take a deep breath.

Comment: @cr125rider My monitor is calibrated (both of them, in fact) and I still find this contrast inconvenient. Also talking about how "too much contrast" can be harmful when the context is that there is hardly any contrast doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @cr125rider My monitors are calibrated with a colorimeter, but I'm sure I just did that wrong. Clearly the only reasonable explanation is that everybody who's complaining has badly calibrated monitors. Would you mind telling us your age range and visual acuity? I'll go ahead and assume: twenty something and pretty good.

Comment: if a design depends on nuances of monitor calibration, is it a good design?

Comment: @cr125rider The page you quote shows no tests but does show its belief in contrast by being think back letters on white background i.e. the most contrast you can do. I would note that the text is wonderfully readable much better than SOs