# The botched Stack Overflow re-design review process

Tags: discussion, design

So, Stack Overflow changed, and we have the (oh-so-familiar) chorus of "hating the redesign" and "how can I make it look like it used to" that any large website can come to expect with a style change. I'll just make it clear that despite [my own (hopefully constructive) criticism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283715/contrast-and-readability), I'm happy that the look and feel of Stack Overflow is being tweaked.

It's important to stay current.

What is clear is that the redesign took a substantial number of users by surprise. This has lead to a lot of frustration of the type detailed above. I think that those involved in the rollout of this change should be asking what went wrong and work a process that makes change less abrupt.

Yes, this whole redesign was tested here on meta. I wasn't aware of it, and despite being a relatively regular meta user, the changes went over my head. Meta is a different site. It looks different. I wasn't lucky enough to spot any kind of suggestion that the changes on meta were part of a larger process, and I'd bet that I wasn't alone.

I'd suggest that for subsequent "big-bang" design rollouts perhaps a site mirror (or a means of previewing the changes on the main site in a non-permanent fashion) be set up to showcase the changes, and banner announcements inform *all* stakeholders that the change is coming and invite them to the site mirror/use style preview controls to provide their opinion. This way, rather than imagining the changes to one website applied to another, users get a concrete look at the designers' vision in the context in which they will use it.

Meta is a different site. It looks different and people don't interact with it in the same way that they do with the main site. Correlating change here on meta with the main site isn't easy.

Comment: I may be spending too much time on Meta but: as soon as this part was redesigned, it was noticed and discussions flared up. Lots of tweaking followed, and bit by bit Meta got better. It's .. *unfortunate* Meta is used differently enough for lots of other possible improvements to be overlooked, and so these only surface now the new style went "live".

Comment: However one main issue with meta its readability has had no response http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229862/could-we-mute-the-theme-a-little#comment761072_229862 - I stopped looking regularly as it is so uncomfortable to read - but I see it is unanswered  as is the same issue on this meta http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283715/contrast-and-readability?lq=1

Comment: I would hardly describe this as a "big-bang design rollout." Effectively no layout changed - everything is exactly where it used to be and works the same way; there is no interface change to relearn. Some typefaces changed size, spacing, light color changing.  Me personally? I like my fonts as small as possible, and felt briefly like "dang, the fonts are bigger, oh well."  Ignore the lingering complaints, and congratulations to the design team. Know that they will make minor adjustments until everything is settled.

Comment: If you want to talk big bangs, lookup the 2013 Flickr redesign, for example.

Comment: @Mark: Not only that, but one doesn't expect changes to code blocks to be noticed on meta, where the focus is not on code.

Comment: The only issue I see is that the new design was deployed on the main site before feedback was taken into account. For example, my [question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283617/the-re-design-has-broken-the-user-flag-history-page) talks about a problem [already reported](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update/277218#277218) back in november...

Comment: everyone hates it at first..

Comment: Bigger? The font on the main page looks way smaller to me than I remember it having been... not unreadably small, but small enough that I don't think it looks that great, readability-wise. (I don't have a screengrab of what it actually used to look like; I think it might actually be the same size, just a *thinner* font?) I'm not sure what other changes there were - nothing else so far seems super noticeable in an annoying way - but the font change is definitely not the best.

Comment: "It's important to stay current". StackExchange is one of the largest interactive sites on the planet. Whatever it does, it defines "current". But I don't mind the new layout. The only thing that really *really* irritates me is that visited links don't stand out any more. I just don't get it. What's the ergonomic rationale behind using a color that hardly differs, *if* you decide to use a different color?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't notice there *was* a redesign until I saw all the complaints on meta.

Comment: I noticed it when I had to move closer to the monitor on my laptop because I was having serious difficulty reading anything on the site. I then used the option in FF to increase the size of the fonts but I still had eye strain. I went up stairs to the desktop and on my 27 inch monitor the fonts were also very difficult to read and more eye strain. I put SO to sleep over night and then the next morning I sought meta to figure out how to revert the change that was causing my 43 year old eyes so much discomfort.

Comment: The site looks great, and while layout is different, the color scheme is very similar. radical color scheme change, and moving my links around, bug me. this did not of those

Comment: "It's important to stay current"--in the fashion world.  You know, "gray is the new black" or "black is the new mauve" or whatever the heck it is this year.  But  in font choice?  "Calibri is the new Arial"?  "Batang is the new Cambria"?

Comment: Just wait until [the new profile page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244238/56338) lands. That doesn't just change some fonts but completely throws out any usability in the hope that it might look more impressive.

Answer (score 41):

> I think that those involved in the roll out of this change should be asking what went wrong and work a process that makes change less abrupt.

That process has existed for years: it's called "frog boiling". The idea is, you make changes *very slowly*, let people get used to each one before rolling out the next. If there's a real problem, that's easy to roll back; if someone just *doesn't like change* then they have more time to get used to it.

Don't believe me? Compare the front page of SO in 2010 to the one *just prior* to the latest set of changes:

[image: before]
[image: after]

(click through to the full archives for an even better view of what all has changed)

That's a *lot* of little redesigns that've snuck in over the years, and of course it doesn't even reflect the huge number of of changes to things like question rendering and tag pages. It's a testament to how well this process works that you didn't realize it already existed...

...Unfortunately, it's *extremely* resource-intensive. Remember, there isn't just *one site* anymore, there are 133 + meta sites + SE.com + Careers. And folks expect them all to look *somewhat* consistent: poke around here a bit, or dig through the design tag on [the *old* MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) - we've had a fair number of reports/requests over the years that boiled down to, "why doesn't *this* site look like *that* site?"

So the design team decided to make a big push for consistency all at once, to at least fix the major discrepancies between SO, Careers, PTSO and JASO, and to lay some groundwork for making this all a bit less painful as we continue to grow.

They knew it was going to be rough. That's why they [baked the design here on Meta for nearly two months](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update), addressing scores of complaints in the process, before releasing it on SO. But it wasn't possible to catch every problem, and even if it had been folks would've still been irked by the fact that *multiple things changed*. That's the trade-off: a rough patch now, vs. another year+ of slow, incremental changes while bugs and inconsistencies continued to accumulate.

Comment: No they don't reply to issues they don';t want to on meta see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229862/could-we-mute-the-theme-a-little#comment761030_229862

Comment: Any time you raise an issue with design, screenshots and specific suggestions are all but essential - depending on your platform, what you see might be significantly different from what others see.

Comment: False dichotomy.  The options are not very very slowly or surprise.  You could have put popups and banners on the main site, as just as one possible option.

Comment: Yes, pop-ups always improve websites. WTF are you talking about, @Ben?

Comment: @Shog9 well if the site was full of pop-ups I would get infuriated with the site, not with the terrible questions.... would that be an improvement?

Comment: @Shop9: Obviously not on every page, but once per user or once per day.  Haven't you ever seen announcements done well?

Comment: I have, @Ben - but never with pop-ups. Annoying someone with your announcement is a great way to get them to not like whatever you're announcing. The announcement was listed on just about every page of the site for a solid week; doesn't mean folks read it.

Comment: @Shog9 I will give shots if I can take a shot of the new and old at the same time so I can see the difference otherwise support will always say it is my setup - i.e. provide a beta running in parallel - which I have not raised a bug

Comment: I just want to add that in the frog boiling experiment a part of the frog's brain was removed. A regular frog would jump out of the boiling water just fine.

Comment: @BenVoigt - You can't have a false dichotomy when no one claimed it was a dichotomy in the first place. Fuzzy logic plays a part here. The dichotomy would involve either saving up all changes and putting them out all at once (which it is clear from the answer is not what has happened with the progressive changes over time), or rolling all changes out one at a time very slowly (also not what is happening), so what exactly about the post makes you think they are inferring a false dichotomy? It is clear we sit somewhere in the middle already.

Comment: Things shouldn't be made easier for the design team at the expense of your users. I've been active on SO for about three years and this latest design is my least favorite. In fact it's the only time I've had to actually download a browser extension so I could overwrite the CSS with my own to make it readable again.

Comment: The tradeoff isn't users vs design team, @j08691. The tradeoff here is batching up some changes vs. not making them at all. Trust me, the design team doesn't like annoying users - that's sorta the opposite of what they're here to do.

Comment: I thought the process was called "post-mortem", which is to look at what you did and how it went well or badly and what can be improved. Frog-boiling, which your post details, isn't related to the quote at the top of your post, I think.

Comment: Read the quote again.

Answer (score -1):

The world is full of people with impaired tolerance for cheese movement. Their predictable distress at the change in the design of a website does not amount to *anyone* botching *anything*.

Comment: Not wanting to be surprised is not so simply dismissed as aversion to change.

Comment: I don't know if I agree with it in the context of the post, but "impaired tolerance for cheese movement" did make me laugh. `:-)`

Comment: Agreed. Either the design was going to be changed or it was going to stay the same. No amount of warning or testing or frog boiling will reach every single person. People *are* going to be "surprised" no matter what you do. Even if you'd go to everyone's house individually and try to break it to them slowly, they'd still be surprised.

Comment: You can't just dismiss things as "people are aversive to change". People are aversive to change *for a reason*.

Comment: I was surprised by the change. I use meta and did notice it was different.  But I had no idea it was going to be applied to SO as well.  BTW I don't mind the new look. Just reporting in that it was a surprise.

Comment: This is of course the case in general, but the surprise and distress at various specific questionable design decisions (and outright bugs that have already been acknowledged and/or fixed) strongly points to actual botching going on to some degree. "Oh it's just users being users" is disingenuous when there's legitimate bugs being reported that could have been avoided.

Comment: So, just out of curiosity - is there any way for someone to actually have a reasonable objection to either the form of a change or the way that changed is managed, and not simply be dismissed out of hand by this sort of knee-jerk "all change good, all thought bad" attitude? I don't care much about the design change - the new design is ugly, but no more than the old, and time wasted on it is simply time wasted. But I don't like knee-jerk dismissal of someone's apparently serious concerns. That seems rude, to me.

Comment: @Jon I think constructive feedback is perfectly fine and should be supplied. Any new software almost inevitably has bugs, even "just" a design change. Let's help iron those out. But as soon as we get into meta discussions about "botched changes" it becomes pointless; it's just complaining all the way down from here.

Comment: @deceze Surely complaining is the main function here on meta, no? :) I say, let a million whinges bloom!

Comment: @Jon Sure, way ahead of you. I'm complaining about complaining, aren't I? ;)

Comment: The voting on this question is pretty entertaining.

Comment: While you may have a point, be scared of going to work for companies that require you to read "Who moved my cheese"; it's a warning there's likely to be constant unmanageable change.